# How can I use custom icon in react-styled components?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use custom icons instead of the react-icons.

```
import { FaMagento } from 'react-icons/fa';
```

and

```
export const SocialIcon = styled(FaMagento)`
margin-right: 10px;
`;
```

instead of the FaMagento, I want to use my own icon, how?

Comment: As usual method import your css on main `app.js` or add css on `public index.html`. Then add the className to the component

Comment: is there any solution for this way?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where you attempt using a non-react-icons icon? I.E. where you import the icon and style and export it? Is this even a `styled-components` related question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example, you have an svg icon:

```
function AnalyticsIcon(props) {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}
    >
      <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path
         .
         .
         .
         .
         .
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}


const StyledIcon = styled(AnalyticsIcon)`
  svg {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
  }
  
  path {
    fill: red;
  }
`
```

Your Icon Component only needs to accept className as props.